# Rails - Elasticsearch: Cannot create index on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, heroku

I reainstalled my Bonsai-Elasticsearch addon on Heroku due recent lack of use. It used to work well before but now when I type this in my rails console:

```
 Lead.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force:true
```

I get this error:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest ([400]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The
>   mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless
>   include_type_name is set to
>   true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The mapping
>   definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless
>   include_type_name is set to true."},"status":400})

How can I fix this issue?

versions: 
Rails: 5.2.2
Ruby: 2.6.3
elasticsearch-model: 6.0.0
elasticsearch-rails: 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bonsai Elasticsearch we have to create an index at our own.

you can create an index of your post model by

```
curl -XPUT https://your:bonsai@url-here.us-east-1.bonsai.io/posts
```

You can get your Bonsai Url by

```
heroku config | grep BONSAI
```

[This](https://seejohnplay.com/2014/09/deploying-elasticsearch-on-heroku-with-rails-4/) is the best tutorial I found you can use it.

More than this you can import your model in elasticsearch by

```
heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Post' FORCE=true
```

if You face the same error you mentioned above, by running the above command then you should try to change your bonsai & other elasticsearch gems which should be compatible with elasticsearch version.